# one-parameter family of embeddings

Tags: general-topology, definition, differential-topology

I'm working on the following Lemma of the proof of Milnor:

Suppose that the vector field $v$ on $U$ corresponds to
$$ v' =df \circ v \circ f^{-1}$$
on $U'$ under a diffeomorphism $f: U \to U'$. The the index of $v$ at an isolated zero $z$ is equal to the index of $v'$ at $f(z)$.
In his proof he used the notion of a "one-parameter family of embeddings". What is the definition of such a family? I never met one before. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

A "one parameter family of embeddings" is a function
$$
t \mapsto f_t
$$
where $t$ typically ranges over the reals (or something like the open interval $-1 < t < 1$), and each $f_t$ is an embedding of some fixed manifold $M$ into some other manifold $K$ (where $K$ is often $\Bbb R^n$).

As an example, considering $M = S^1$, and $K = S^1 \times S^1$, the function
$$
f_t (\theta) = (t, \theta)
$$
is, for each fixed $t$, an embedding of $S^1$ as one factor of $S^1 \times S^1$.

In short: it's a path in the space of embeddings. I suspect that many authors assume it's smooth as a function of $t$, but it should certainly be continuous as a function of $t$ at the very least.